# C++:openCV error

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rgb

hi all i am trying to get the RGB for a pixel in an image using C++ openCV 2.4.5

but i get this error when i compile .

it loads the image will but the exception arise when i am trying to get the RGB for a pixel

can any one help me please ?

[image]

the following code loads an image and find the RGB for a pixel at index 25,4 
 my code is :

```
 #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv/cv.h>
    #include <opencv/highgui.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;
    int main()
    {
        int x;
        Mat input = imread("C:/red.jpg");
        if (input.empty())
            {
                std::cout << "!!! Failed imread(): image not found" << std::endl;
                cin>>x;
                return 0;
                // don't let the execution continue, else imshow() will crash.
            }
        imshow("input", input);
         Vec3f pixel = input.at<Vec3f>(25, 40);
         if( !pixel[0])
         {
             std::cout << "!!! Failed pixel(): image not found" << std::endl;
                cin>>x;
                return 0;
         }
            int b = pixel[0];
            int g = pixel[1];
            int r = pixel[2];
        cout<<b;
        cout <<" ";
        cout<<r;
        cout <<" ";
        cout <<g;
        cin>>b;

        /*




        // detect squares after filtering...
        */
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You image is probably of type CV_8UC3, which means the value of a pixel is stored as 3-channel 8-bit uchar. In

```
Vec3f pixel = input.at<Vec3f>(25, 40);
```

you are trying to access pixel values as floats, since in OpenCV `Vec3f` is defined as `typedef Vec<float, 3> Vec3f;`. This causes your program to crush. Instead it should be:

```
Vec3b pixel = input.at<Vec3b>(25, 40);
```

In OpenCV `Vec3b` is defined as `typedef Vec<uchar, 3> Vec3b;`, which is what you want.

[Here's the documentation for cv:: Vec](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=vec3f#vec) data type.

**EDIT** You can output the pixel data simply with

```
cout << pixel << endl;
```

or like this:

```
printf("[%u, %u, %u]", pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2]);
```

or like this:

```
int b = static_cast<int>(pixel[0]);
int g = static_cast<int>(pixel[1]);
int r = static_cast<int>(pixel[2]);
cout<< "[" << b <<", " << g << ", " << r << "]" << endl;
```

Comment: @mohhamad Has the answer been useful to you? If so, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should use :

```
Mat input = imread("C://red.jpg");
```

instead of :

```
Mat input = imread("C:/red.jpg");
```